# How to filter results and update a google map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Last Query from me about this, 
I have done everything I need to at this point except for one thing, no mater what I try I cant seem to get the search to show items on the list and markers on the map. 
Ive tried to use filter but can only get the list to narrow down when the input field has something. I cant seem to get the markers and List to change.
Here is the code I have so far

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper 
} from 'google-maps-react';

var  AllPlaces = [
{
"name" : "Pizza",
"lat": "40.7589",
"lng":"-73.9851",
},

{
"name" : "Cookies",
"lat": "40.7690",
"lng":"-73.9952",
},
{
"name" : "Bagels",
"lat": "40.7489",
"lng":"-73.9751",
}
]

class MapContainer extends Component {
state = {
showingInfoWindow: false,
activeMarker: {},
selectedPlace: {},
query:'',
};

markers = []


onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) => {
this.setState({
  selectedPlace: props,
  activeMarker: marker,
  showingInfoWindow: true
 });
}

onLiClick = (i) =>{
this.setState({
    showingInfoWindow: true,
    activeMarker: this.markers[i],
    selectedPlace: AllPlaces[i]
})
}


onMapClicked = (props) => {
if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
  this.setState({
    showingInfoWindow: false,
    activeMarker: null
  })
}
}


CreateInputField = () => (
<input
  placeholder = "Search Nearby Places"
/>
)

findPlaces = () => (
<ol className='Places'>
  {AllPlaces.map((arrayItem, index)=>
    <li
    key = {index}
    className='Place'
    onClick={() => {this.onLiClick(index)}}
    >{arrayItem.name}</li>
  )}
</ol>
);

render() {
return (
  <div className = 'map-container' style= 
{{marginleft:'250px'}}>
    <div>
      <div className = 'sideMenu'>
        <div className = 'List'>
          <h1 className = 'title'> Places to Eat 
</h1>
            {this.CreateInputField()}
        </div>
        <div className = 'PlaceList'>
          {this.findPlaces()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14}
      initialCenter = {{lat:40.7589, lng:-73.9851}}
      onClick={this.onMapClicked}>
      {AllPlaces.map((marker, i) =>
          <Marker
          ref={(e) => {if (e) this.markers[i] = 
 e.marker}}
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          title = {marker.name}
          name={marker.name}
          position = 
{{lat:marker.lat,lng:marker.lng}}
          />
      )}
      <InfoWindow
        onOpen={this.windowHasOpened}
        onClose={this.windowHasClosed}
        marker={this.state.activeMarker}
        visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}>
        <div>
          <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h1>
        </div>
      </InfoWindow>
    </Map>
  </div>
 );
 }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
apiKey: 'AIzaSyC21SntdNn1vCb5VOAujCPIM7a9p5XkvRs'
})(MapContainer)
```

I have been stuck on this for about 2 weeks now and just need a little guidance on it.

Comment: Maybe you should hide your api key? I know it's not an answer but just a safety measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I've created an array inside state to store the filtered out locations. When you type it filters and updates the locations. :)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper 
} from 'google-maps-react';

var  AllPlaces = [
{
"name" : "Pizza",
"lat": "40.7589",
"lng":"-73.9851",
},

{
"name" : "Cookies",
"lat": "40.7690",
"lng":"-73.9952",
},
{
"name" : "Bagels",
"lat": "40.7489",
"lng":"-73.9751",
}
]

class MapContainer extends Component {
state = {
showingInfoWindow: false,
activeMarker: {},
selectedPlace: {},
query:'',
filteredPlaces: []
};

markers = []


onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) => {
this.setState({
  selectedPlace: props,
  activeMarker: marker,
  showingInfoWindow: true
 });
}

onLiClick = (i) =>{
this.setState({
    showingInfoWindow: true,
    activeMarker: this.markers[i],
    selectedPlace: AllPlaces[i]
})
}


onMapClicked = (props) => {
if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
  this.setState({
    showingInfoWindow: false,
    activeMarker: null
  })
}
}


CreateInputField = () => (
<input
  placeholder = "Search Nearby Places"
  onChange={(event) => this.setState({filteredPlaces: AllPlaces.filter(place => !place.name.startsWith(event.target.value))})}
/>
)

render() {
return (
  <div className = 'map-container' style= 
{{marginleft:'250px'}}>
    <div>
      <div className = 'sideMenu'>
        <div className = 'List'>
          <h1 className = 'title'> Places to Eat 
</h1>
            {this.CreateInputField()}
        </div>
        <div className = 'PlaceList'>
          <ol className='Places'>
            {AllPlaces.map((arrayItem, index)=> 
            !this.state.filteredPlaces.includes(arrayItem) &&
              <li
              key = {index}
              className='Place'
              onClick={() => {this.onLiClick(index)}}
              >{arrayItem.name}</li>
            )}
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14}
      initialCenter = {{lat:40.7589, lng:-73.9851}}
      onClick={this.onMapClicked}>
      {AllPlaces.map((marker, i) => 
        !this.state.filteredPlaces.includes(marker) &&
          <Marker
          ref={(e) => {if (e) this.markers[i] = 
 e.marker}}
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          title = {marker.name}
          name={marker.name}
          position = 
{{lat:marker.lat,lng:marker.lng}}
          />
      )}
      <InfoWindow
        onOpen={this.windowHasOpened}
        onClose={this.windowHasClosed}
        marker={this.state.activeMarker}
        visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}>
        <div>
          <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h1>
        </div>
      </InfoWindow>
    </Map>
  </div>
 );
 }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
apiKey: 'AIzaSyC21SntdNn1vCb5VOAujCPIM7a9p5XkvRs'
})(MapContainer)
```

Comment: youre saving my life right now haha, I tried in the code but when I type anything it removes all the markers and clears the whole list, this is def a step in the right direction here is the source
https://github.com/JustJin28/react-map-the-one-that-will-pass
im going to keep trying at it, I really appreciate the help, if I could take you out for a drink I would

Comment: Edit, it does show but cant account for capital letters so if I start by typing lowercase it will get rid of all the markers